# Generate samples from other samples

Tags: probability-distributions, sampling

Given a family of continuous random samples $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ that approximate some unknown probability distribution. How can I generate more samples that fit to the same unknown distibution?

Assumption: I first have to estimate the unknown distribution and then generate samples from this distribution.

If my assumption is valid, how do I do this estimation?
Otherwise, is there a direct approach to generate samples from other samples?
What are the drawbacks?

Comment: Not sure if that is what you have in mind, but [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29) comes to mind...

Comment: I've heard of it, but I never worked with it before, so I will check it out.

Comment: In case you haven't figured it out by now, I think nonparametric bootstrapping is what you had in mind, although you did not mention any _purpose_ for taking _more samples_ from the same population. Note that re-sampling of this kind does _not_ provide additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three related topics. Suppose, we are given the following vector `x` of $n = 100$ observations rounded to two places, with sample mean $\bar X = 2.0798$, and sample variance
$S^2 = 1.13149.$

```
0.80 2.06 2.10 1.13 2.26 1.25 2.79 1.22 1.33 0.50 1.81 2.76 1.65 1.77 2.47 1.20 1.88 1.32 1.75 1.71
0.66 1.76 1.76 2.44 2.85 6.66 3.61 0.64 3.37 0.89 3.14 1.32 0.96 0.86 1.29 2.41 1.91 1.06 0.93 3.81
3.57 0.83 3.28 3.53 1.26 1.74 2.09 1.57 3.21 2.08 1.76 1.35 2.07 1.91 1.94 1.12 1.14 5.72 1.88 1.93
1.11 1.59 1.35 2.30 1.39 1.90 1.30 2.00 3.71 2.81 1.32 4.77 3.04 2.72 2.38 2.10 1.82 2.50 2.38 1.53
1.91 1.01 3.42 2.28 2.86 1.73 2.63 1.77 2.61 0.78 1.08 1.73 1.16 4.20 2.52 3.87 1.83 1.21 1.90 3.36
```

You might find [these notes by C. Wickham](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~vigre/activities/bootstrap/2006/wickham_stati.pdf) of interest.

**Parametric bootstrap.** This is a 're-sampling' procedure for the
purpose of finding a confidence interval of a population parameter. Here, suppose the parameter is the mean $\mu$ of the population from which our
observations were randomly sampled.

In order to carry out this procedure, we need to know the *distribution family* of the population from which the data were generated. Suppose it is $Gamma(\text{shape}=\theta, \text{rate}=\lambda),$ where $\mu = \theta/\lambda.$
For our sample, the *method of moments* estimates are 
$\hat \theta = \bar X^2/S^2 = 3.822927,\,$ 
$\hat \lambda = \bar X/S^2 = 1.838114,$ and
$\hat \mu = \bar X$ denoted `obs.mean` below.

In order to find a confidence interval for $\mu,$ we would like to know the
distribution of the random variable $D = \bar X - \mu.$ If we knew its distribution, we could find values $L < 0$ and $U > 0$ cutting off the lower and upper
2.5% of the probability from that distribution to obtain
$$P(L < D = \bar X - \mu < U) = 0.95,$$
and hence the 95% confidence interval $(\bar X - U, \bar X - L)$ for $\mu.$

However, not knowing these value $L$ and $U,$ we enter the 'bootstrap'
world', in which we take a large number $B$ of re-samples from
$Gamma(\hat \theta, \hat \lambda),$ finding the bootstrap mean $\bar X^*$
of each sample. We emulate the distribution of $D$ with the many
values $D^* = \bar X* - \bar X,$ where in the bootstrap world $\bar X$
is a temporary proxy for $\mu.$

Returning to the real world, we approximate $L$ by $L^*$ and $U$ by $U^*,$
were $L^*$ and $U^*$ cut 2.5% from the lower and upper tails of the the
re-sample of $B$ values of $D^*.$ Then our 95% parametric bootstrap CI for $\mu$
is $(\bar X - U^*, \bar X - L^*),$ in which $\bar X$ has returned to its
original role as the mean of the original sample. The resulting CI is
$(1.87. 2.29).$ The R program to obtain this CI is shown below, in which
suffixes `.re` replace the superscripted *'s above.

```
obs.mean = mean(x)
B = 10000;  d.re=numeric(B)
for(i in 1:B) {
  x.re = rgamma(100, alp.mme, lam.mme)
  d.re[i] = mean(x.re) - obs.mean }
obs.mean - quantile(d.re, c(.975,.025))
##     97.5%     2.5% 
##  1.865877 2.285135
```

**Nonparametric bootstrap.** As your problem is stated, you give no clue
as to the distribution family of the population. In that case, the
procedure is much the same. However, we cannot re-sample from a distribution
with parameters estimated from the data. Instead, we take re-samples of
size $n = 100$ *with replacement* from the original data `x`.

The rationale is that the data provide an empirical CDF of the unknown
population distribution. All that is known about the population is that
it is capable of producing the 100 observations we have at hand.
The resulting nonparametric bootstrap is $(1.86, 2.82)$.

```
obs.mean = mean(x)
B = 10000;  d.re=numeric(B)
for(i in 1:B) {
  x.re = sample(x, 100, repl=T)
  d.re[i] = mean(x.re) - obs.mean }
obs.mean - quantile(d.re, c(.975,.025))
##    97.5%     2.5% 
## 1.861853 2.282402
```

***The truth.*** The data were simulated from $Gamma(4, 2)$ with mean $\mu = 2.$
So in this case we have the nice advantage of knowing that our CIs actually
do contain the true value of $\mu.$ In R, you can simulate *exactly* the
sample shown by using the same seed for the random number generator I did.
Also, $ \hat \theta = 3.82,$ and $\hat \lambda = 1.84.$ Maximum likelihood
estimators are preferable, but messier, and this is too long already.
Moroever, the sample size $n = 100$ is large enough that it would be safe
to find a t CI for $\mu: (1.83, 3.82)$

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rgamma(100, 4, 2);  round(x, 2)
a = mean(x);  v = var(x)

lam.mme = a/v;  tht.mme = a^2/v
lam.mme;  tht.mme
## 1.838114
## 3.822927

pm = c(-1,1);  t.cut = qt(.975, 99)
mean(x) + pm*t.cut/sd(x)/sqrt(100)
## 1.893273 2.266346
```

It is important to understand that bootstrap re-sampling is a *method of
data analysis.* No new information is 'generated' by re-sampling.
Re-sampling is just a clever way to use the information in the original sample.

**Density estimator.** Density estimators were mentioned in the Comment
by @AbishankaSaha. The figure below shows a histogram of the data. The
blue curve is the PDF of $Gamma(4, 2)$ and the red curve is the
default kernel density estimator implemented in R. It might be possible
to sample from the density-estimated distribution, but there is no
more information in the density estimator than in the sample.

```
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
curve(dgamma(x, 4, 2), lwd=2, col="blue", add=T)
lines(density(x), lwd=2, col="red")
rug(x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)? Refer to the book [Density Estimation for Statistics and Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412246201) by Bernard. W. Silverman.

Comment: I am not familiar with it, but I'll have a look into it and check whether I can apply it.